# Error invoking Windows DLL function from Python

Tags: python, c++, windows, dll, ctypes

I have a Windows DLL that exposes a function. Let's call it `Fn`. It takes two `CStrings` as parameters and returns a `CString`:

```
CString Fn(CString a, CString b)
```

The C++ code you see below successfully loads the DLL and invokes `Fn`. A side effect of `Fn` is that it prints the value of parameter `a` to stdtout. So I see:

```
Parameter a has value "A"
```

However, when I do the same from Python, I get:

```
Parameter a has value "B"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000005
```

So `Fn` somehow receives parameter `b` instead of parameter `a`.

**My question is: Why do my function parameters get mangled when calling the DLL from Python, but not from C++?**

In fact, this problem does not only occur when I call `Fn` from Python, but also when I call it from [NSIS](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Main_Page) via:

```
System::Call "My::Fn(m 'A', m 'B') m .r0"
```

I thought that it might be a problem with the calling convention. So I changed `windll.LoadLibrary` to `cdll.LoadLibrary`. Unfortunately, this produces the exact same output.

## Python code (not working)

```
from ctypes import *
f = windll.LoadLibrary('My.dll').Fn
f.argtypes = [c_char_p, c_char_p]
f.restype = c_char_p
f(b"A", b"B")
```

## C++ Code (working)

```
#include <atlstr.h>

typedef CString (*Fn)(CString, CString);

int main( void ) {
    HINSTANCE dll = LoadLibrary("My.dll");
    Fn f = (Fn) GetProcAddress(dll, "Fn");
    f("A", "B");
    FreeLibrary(dll);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++ class `CString` is not a pointer, making this very approach flawed.

Comment: *ctypes* stands for ***C*** (**!!! NOT !!!** ***C++***) types.

Comment: At the very least (I would venture to suggest) you should declare/define your exported function with an explicit `__stdcall` (probably) or `__cdecl` (maybe). But I'm not a `Python` programmer, so don't know what the calling convention is from that language. Perhaps use plain old character strings rather than CString for your interlingual (?) calls.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I don't have access to the implementation of `Fn`, but I may be able to get the implementer to use a string type other than `CString`. What should I tell him to use?

Comment: The only string type that will be callable from python is `char*`

Comment: see https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#calling-functions

Comment: If you have a C++ API, I suggest using either [cppyy](https://cppyy.readthedocs.io/en/latest) or [Cython](https://cython.org). You'll need a supported C++ compiler. If it's a small interface, you could also write a C wrapper library that links with the C++ library, and then use this C API with ctypes or cffi. (FYI, in x64 cdecl and stdcall are the same calling convention. They're different in the 32-bit x86 ABI.)

Comment: Or https://pypi.org/project/pybind11.

Comment: @AlanBirtles also `wchar_t*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the comments to my question, I managed to find a solution.

The problem seems to have been that `CString` is an MFC concept that neither Python nor NSIS know about. Changing `Fn`'s signature to

```
LPCTSTR Fn(LPCTSTR, LPCTSTR)
```

solved the issue.